# adding anonymous account to registerd account

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

I have answered a question and earned 10+ reputation when i was anonymous user but now I am registered one  and want to move this reputation to the registered account. Please tell me the procedure of the same. Thanks in advance.

following is the link where I have earned it.
[How can I add a searchview to my Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213746/how-can-i-add-a-searchview-to-my-android-app)

Comment: dupe of [How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or Google / Facebook / registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/154443)

Comment: I've just flagged the answer you want to have associated as NAA because it is little more than a link, you were lucky to get an upvote for it. If you want the reputation, then just answer more questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your accounts have been merged. The next time please simply flag a post from your other account and mention that you'd like them merged.

Oh, and that answer you referred to was not an real answer at all - just throwing in a link is not really an answer - so it has been deleted. See [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Ok thanks for that I will take care hereafter